# Posting images to server, but the size is very small

Tags: android, bitmap, android-volley, android-bitmap

I am sending images to server using Volley. Below is my code to compress and converting bitmaps to bytes. I want to send images in actual size, if I specify `bmp=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp,500,400, true)` images are stretched.

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}
```

This is the   size which i am getting on server, its really small:

[image]

Below is the code which is sending to server:

```
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String,String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    for(int i=0; i<bitmapArray.size(); i++){
        Log.d("size of array is",String.valueOf(bitmapArray.size()));
      params.put("image"+(i+1),getStringImage(bitmapArray.get(i)));
      params.put("name"+(i+1), "name"+(i+1));
    } 
    return params; 
}
```

Comment: Make sure the Bitmap you're passing to `getStringImage` is not already compressed or downsized

Comment: I think you are using the Bitmap coming from the `onActivityResult` which not the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

if you using the bitmap returning the Camera app Intent without passing any file url or uri as below, it will return only a thumbnail image bitmap which is low quality image of small size, so if you resize it will look streched.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

To get full quality image, you need to provide the Camera Intent a file path in the extra, so that Camera app will save the image there, later upon onActivityResult you should read the image from the file path and convert that to bitmap, that will be a full quality image.

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

Please make sure the filepath or uri you provide to camera app has necessary permissions.

if you are using External Storage Permission in your app, this will be easy, else you there are ways to give permission to the camera app.

Here is one such sample i did for my work - https://github.com/santbob/AppPrivateImageUpload